# how to plot dynamic high in 5 min chart in pine script

Tags: pine-script

On a 5min chart, I want to plot horizontal line on high of the candle. This line should move up if the next candle is higher then current candle. This moving should stop for the day once the next candle high is less than current candle.

Thanks a lot for looking at the query and helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)
var l = line.new(0, high, 0, high, extend=extend.right)
var h = high
if high >= h
    h := high
    line.set_xy1(l, bar_index[1], h)
    line.set_xy2(l, bar_index, h)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but there is no line shown on plot. Also one query, the code looks like it will work till the point when high keeps on increasing and has first drop. But what if the high goes again above 'h' ? It will change 'h', which it should not after first reversal. So the first reversal high should be final value for the line.